# Sqlite query all the missing ids

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got two tables in my DB, **users** and **gifts**. The user table got id and data, the gifts table got gift_id, user_id and data.

*gitst.user_id associated with users.id*

How can I get all the user_id from gifts table that not appear in users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using the `except` operator.

```
select user_id from gifts
except 
select id from users
```

`Except` gives you the difference of two sets.

Let's say set A = {1,2,3} B={3,4,5,6}.

A-B = {1,2} because `3` exists in both the sets and 1,2 exist in A but not in B

B-A = {4,5,6} 3 is common to both sets and 4,5,6 exist in B but not in A

You can also do

```
select user_id from gifts 
where user_id not in (select id from users)
```

or

```
select user_id from gifts g
where not exists (select 1 from users where id = g.user_id)
```

Comment: Users don't have user_id they got id, can you please explain in more details how the except query works.

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id from gifts not exists(select id from users)
```